# ANKO paddingTop - Val cannot be reassigned

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

I want to put paddingTop on my `verticalLayout`, however it prompts with a warning 
**Val cannot be reassigned**. I assume I am tackling this issue the wrong way, however the resources online seems scarce.

Below is my AnkoComponent:

```
class MainActivityUi : AnkoComponent<MainActivity> {
override fun createView(ui: AnkoContext<MainActivity>) = with(ui) {
    verticalLayout {
        textView {
            text = "Input"
            textColor = Color.BLACK
            textAlignment = View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER
        }
        textView {
            text = "Output"
            textColor = Color.BLACK
            textAlignment = View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER
        }
        linearLayout {
            button {

                text = "0"
            }.lparams(width = wrapContent, height = matchParent) {
                gravity = Gravity.CENTER
                weight = 5f
                margin = dip(3)
            }
            button {
                text = "1"
            }.lparams(width = wrapContent, height = matchParent) {
                gravity = Gravity.CENTER
                weight = 5f
                margin = dip(3)
            }
        }
        linearLayout {
            button {
                text = "/"
            }.lparams(width = wrapContent, height = matchParent) {
                gravity = Gravity.CENTER
                weight = 5f
                margin = dip(3)
            }
            button {
                text = "*"
            }.lparams(width = wrapContent, height = matchParent) {
                gravity = Gravity.CENTER
                weight = 2.5f
                margin = dip(3)
            }
            button {
                text = "-"
            }.lparams(width = wrapContent, height = matchParent) {
                gravity = Gravity.CENTER
                weight = 2.5f
                margin = dip(3)
            }
            button {
                text = "+"
            }.lparams(width = wrapContent, height = matchParent) {
                gravity = Gravity.CENTER
                weight = 2.5f
                margin = dip(3)
            }
        }
        linearLayout {
            button {
                text = "base10"
            }.lparams(width = matchParent, height = wrapContent){
                margin = dip(3)
            }
        }
        linearLayout {
            button {
                text = "calculate!"
            }.lparams(width = matchParent, height = wrapContent){
                margin = dip(3)
            }
        }
        lparams { //This is the culprit!
            paddingTop = dip(200)
        }
    }
}
```

Neither `marginTop` or `paddingTop` works, however the IDE suggests it when typing in `margin` or `padding`. Simply `padding` or `margin` does not prompt an error, but I am looking for only making space at the very top of my component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `topPadding` instead `paddingTop`

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change:

```
verticalLayout {
    ...
    lparams {
        ...
    }
}
```

To read instead:

```
verticalLayout {
    ...
}.lparams {
    ...
}
```

I haven't used the Anko library before, but the above change comes from this comment in their GitHub project: https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/issues/392#issuecomment-304659964

Comment: Both declarations seem to work the same. I got a tip - the paddingTop is not a anko variable, however the IDE suggests it, which was quite confusing to me. Instead I had to use topPadding :)